# How to change numeric numpy array to char array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change a numeric numpy array to char array using python,for example,

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape([5,5])
```

How to change array a to char array ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the datatype of the numpy array by using `astype` method. Try below example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(25).reshape([5,5])
a.dtype  #check data type of array it should show int


new = a.astype(str)  #change data type of array to string
new.dtype  #Check the data type again it should show string
```